# Why not getting error in PHP

Tags: php

I'm developing website. I've some pages in which i change the header information and when I host it displays following error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\inetpub\vhosts\jrmds.in\httpdocs\functions\dateprint.php:1) in D:\inetpub\vhosts\jrmds.in\httpdocs\articlemessage.php on line 8
```

But when I run the same code on my local machine I don't get any error. I know It's error but I'm not getting it on my local machine. How to get that error on my local machine so that I can resolve this type of error on local machine and then upload it on server instead of upload it on server and then came to know that some output is already sent and then I'm changing the header.

in php.ini file following value is set for

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Comment: The local machine has not the same configuration as your host. Maybe some extension regarding `date` is missing. Do a `phpinfo()` on your host and local and compare.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

Use the following command in your PHP file (or set it directly inside the *php.ini*):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

---

**From the manual:**

> This determines whether errors should be printed to the screen as part
>   of the output or if they should be hidden from the user.
>
> Value "stderr" sends the errors to stderr instead of stdout. The value
>   is available as of PHP 5.2.4. In earlier versions, this directive was
>   of type boolean.
>
> **Note:**
>
> This is a feature to support your development and **should never be
>   used on production systems** (e.g. systems connected to the internet).

Comment: I put ini_set('display_errors',1) but still not getting those errors.
I have below file structure
header.php contains the menu and logo part
and then index.php in which i've included the header.php at top most position, and then I check for the session variable and if it is not set i redirect user using header("location:...") else user is valid to view page. But i don't get that error that says **"output is already sent and can not modify header"** but i do get on server where i've put the site.

Answer (score 2):

You should use display_errors directive in php.ini

display_errors = Off on production
display_errors = On of development (optional).